# XML Signature (Java)

Tags: java, xml-signature

I am trying to sign a small xml that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test/>
```

I must have something that look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:elc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Arise.and.shine" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-F86143B2B1BBA025BF144915430086958">MYCERTIFICAT</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature Id="SIG-F86143B2B1BBA025BF144915430086961" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="elc soapenv tem" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-C412303BE3B390B3D114265182390669">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="elc tem" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>dx3Bq2k18snVIR+CzEoyLZ3/jRc=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>KSvaK2EneWvtLXFMmynnBFd0h9PPnuipBa3Lib2pchGOtt8K3g8GsHAT5Vg6nGsNpo1e8SeikrNK4KRtUDne3CjvMh+LOajCpfWwl3u7W1yjp52HUODy+uZOfjL+B+9/kcDLyeJTdbB6KLVCwmD3TDuVA7tApR92VFXKTDT8X8DXrKaEl5a7fPLeb6mYfdAWsxY6Ua5KLZN+IGZAJsWi2SdOEhfHtMzbBvFOXokwysmLaYTmcY0GAkMq74Khna36SVUgxpSDDZoeDiHFGyu5CT9ClbJy8WTEAcJzlok1tvtikGzU//Md0ky0u4fuFiKeQlF+Qw/AxRG7SDqbdcLWrA==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-F86143B2B1BBA025BF144915430086959">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-F86143B2B1BBA025BF144915430086960">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-F86143B2B1BBA025BF144915430086958" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-C412303BE3B390B3D114265182390669" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <tem:SendMessage>
            <tem:request>
                <elc:XmlData>
                    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test/>]]></elc:XmlData>
            </tem:request>
        </tem:SendMessage>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can see that there is a lot of information to put in the header, and the signature is separated from the real message to send. This is the code I have:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException;
import javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.CanonicalizationMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.DigestMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignedInfo;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Transform;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfoFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyValue;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Sign {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
    KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, 
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, 
    KeyException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, MarshalException, XMLSignatureException, TransformerException {
        String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");
        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM",(Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());
        Reference ref = fac.newReference("",fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),Collections.singletonList( fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (XMLStructure) null)),null, null);
        SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(
            fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(
                CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE,
                (XMLStructure) null
            ),
            fac.newSignatureMethod(
                    SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, 
                    null
            ),
            Collections.singletonList(ref)
        );

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\Step 1\\mock\\NewJKS.jks");

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(is, null);
        //Enumeration<String> myEnum = keystore.aliases();
        for (Enumeration<String> e = keystore.aliases(); e.hasMoreElements();){
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }               

        String alias = "toto";
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, null); 
        System.out.println(key);
        KeyPair kp = null;
        if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
          // Get certificate of public key
          Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
          // Get public key
          PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
          // Return a key pair
          kp = new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);          
//        System.out.println(kp);
        }


        KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
        KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(kp.getPublic());
        KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv));

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("D:\\Step 1\\mock\\XMLTestData.xml"));
        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(kp.getPrivate(), doc.getDocumentElement());
        XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
        signature.sign(dsc);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc),new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("D:\\Step 1\\mock\\mySignedFile2.xml")));

    }

}
```

What I get is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<test>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>iUqbN+l20aP00zS0qltBAv2oDbc=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>NiLEgObJbPot9kUJQ3kHi2z/1e6SGCqiZbrbAtc1snZp8MxoMothOA3dyqi6sDOBiLfdz7hRdEj+
gMwvkxci+KaqBtK2Rv9l9eE+/X5rjJz0aQM2Dq9kxB3BFwCSLdK0uMoO7YKAr6e6QirRI70npERt
gzAu4mriUpSkm5gbtWg=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <KeyValue>
                <RSAKeyValue>
                    <Modulus>tDcB3pWauMi0lZl7U/1g6Zj2dmeaokXJkbnytLtWCC1tyPsiWGNPxlKygVF+Pm+w4jciJxDzSxex
XY4jKTZz3a7qnq9EE/qo1ESzXpp+tus83iZFpPH+VpqBmcf1eutzSyEAqyYybAWm5p5q+2IqW+9H
UXIjgJczkCX/5nU7M6s=</Modulus>
                    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
                </RSAKeyValue>
            </KeyValue>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</test>
```

My first question is how can I modify my source code to have an enveloping signature?

Comment: Please [`[edit]`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34531932/edit) your question.

Comment: What you are asked to create is a SOAP request with a security header. The JDK offers API to [build](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.html) SOAP documents. [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home) is a library to help you build the security header.

Comment: And you really should not use [SHA-1](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do. Your `<test>` should go in body.
The most I liked is below.

1. Create or mimic the soap Envelope structure with blank header.
   Dynamically get your header and do what you are doing now.. being said Add
   everything in header whatever you want to sign like 
   issuer name or serial number.
2. Pass final document to signing method so it will sign based with body
   information and add it to header.

Good Luck.

Some code snippet it may help.

```
   Element headerElement = null;
   NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Header");
   headerElement = (Element)nodes.item(0);

   // Create an XMLSignature instance
   Element soapsec = doc.createElementNS("", "SOAP-SEC:Signature");
   soapsec.setAttributeNS("", "mustUnderstand", "1");
   soapsec.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:SOAP-SEC", "http://www.schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-10");

   Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
   transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE);
   transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_C14N_WITH_COMMENTS);
   XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc,"",XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);       

   soapsec.appendChild(sig.getElement());
   headerElement.appendChild(soapsec);
   // Specify the transforms
   sig.addDocument("#Body", transforms, org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);


  // Get the certificate and send for signing it will do what you required.
     sig.sign(privateKey);
```